# Opencv linemod throws matching exception

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use linemod in OpenCV.

I successfully added some templates, but when I try to some matching I get the following error:

> Error: Assertion failed (response_map.rows % T == 0) in cv::linemod::linearize, file ...\opencv\sources\modules\rgbd\src\linemod.cpp, line 1108

All images are of the recommended size of 800x600 pixels.

My code:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::linemod::Detector> detector = cv::linemod::getDefaultLINE();

cv::Mat color, mask;
std::vector<cv::Mat> images;

for (int i = 0; i < 419; i++)
{
    images.push_back(cv::imread("Resources/Train/" + std::to_string(i+1) + ".png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));
}

for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
{
    color = images[i];
    // Create image mask
    double thresh = 0;
    double maxValue = 255;
    // Binary Threshold
    cv::threshold(color, mask, thresh, maxValue, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> sources;
    sources.push_back(color);

    // Extract template
    std::string class_id = cv::format("class%d", num_classes);
    cv::Rect bb;
    int template_id = detector->addTemplate(sources, class_id, mask, &bb);
    if (template_id != -1)
    {
        printf("*** Added template (id %d) for new object class %d***\n",
                template_id, num_classes);
        //printf("Extracted at (%d, %d) size %dx%d\n", bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height);
    }

    ++num_classes;
}

std::vector<cv::Mat> sources;
sources.push_back(cv::imread("Resources/Train/1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));
std::vector<cv::linemod::Match> matches;
std::vector<cv::String> class_ids;
std::vector<cv::Mat> quantized_images;
detector->match(sources, 80, matches, class_ids, quantized_images); // ERROR

for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i)
{
    cv::linemod::Match m = matches[i];
    printf("Similarity: %5.1f%%; x: %3d; y: %3d; class: %s; template: %3d\n", m.similarity, m.x, m.y, m.class_id.c_str(), m.template_id);
}
```

The error ist thrown at `detector->match(sources, 80, matches, class_ids, quantized_images);`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's really late, and you've already solved it (kind of). But for the other people who would stumble upon the same issue....

`cv::linemod::getDefaultLINE()` contain the 2 pyramid levels, 5 and 8 respectfully. But for the pyramid level of 8, `pyrDown` is performed (essentially a scale down for a factor of 2).

That said the size of the image should be the multiple of both 5 and 16 (8 for the pyrmaid level times the scaling down factor of 2), namely the **multiple of 80**. And that's what the error comes from (600 is not the multiple of 80).

Comment: is there any documentation available that explains `cv2.linemod` class in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve it myself.
The templates need to be grayscale images of size 800x600 pixels, while the images that I want to match need to be 3-channel color images of size 800x800 pixels. Really confusing...
In the end however the algorithm works really bad. So I didn't end up using it.